# Use Log4net to generate json format log with custom layout/fields?

Tags: c#, logging, log4net

can we use Log4net to generate json format log with custom layout/fields?

I'm using log4net to log some information. Now, because of this and that, we need to log it as json format.

I'm using log4net.Ext.Json for this, it logs the information like this:

```
{"date":"2018-10-29T15:18:26.7785983-07:00","level":"INFO","logger":"Service.Services.LogService","message":"data_length: 10"}
{"date":"2018-10-29T15:18:26.7796462-07:00","level":"INFO","logger":"Service.Services.LogService","message":"max_parallelism: 1"}
```

However, since we will log lots of information, and we will feed this log to another program to analyze. So, we want to output it like:

```
{
  "_index": "error_201843",
  "_type": "error_web",
  "_id": "AWaytV_hi121qded",
  "_version": 1,
  "_source": {
                    "ApplicationSource": "Data Feed",
                    "ErrorType": "RequestTimeout",
                    "XStackTrace": "",
                    "ErrorMessageText": ""
            }
}
```

_index, _typem _id, _version are constant. _source data comes from the actual log fields.

How can we do this? Any ideas? I'm thinking of have a method to build the entire string, then output the string. But it should have a better way to do this, I think.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We have been doing this for some time and can be done using a dynamic object. We have different log event types which are centralized and this allows the flexibility to add whatever information required. The loggingEvent event object is from log4net and an Append override in a custom appender.

```
JsonSerializerSettings _jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings() { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore };

dynamic m = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
m.SessionId = _sessionId;
m.ProcessId = _processId.ToString();
m.ProcessName = _processName;
m.MachineName = _machineName;
m.UserName = _userName;
m.Level = loggingEvent.Level.DisplayName;
m.Domain = loggingEvent.Domain;
m.TimeStamp = loggingEvent.TimeStamp.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff");
m.MessageObject = loggingEvent.MessageObject;
if (loggingEvent.ExceptionObject != null)
{
  m.Exception = loggingEvent.ExceptionObject.ToString();
  m.StackTrace = loggingEvent.ExceptionObject.StackTrace;
}

//Convert the object to a json string
string msg = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(m, Formatting.None, _jsonSerializerSettings);
```